# Tint a hole Linear/Relative Layout when pressed

Tags: android, layout, tint

I've been looking for this, but I didnt find. I already have an `OnTouchListener` variable that tint the buttons and it works perfectly, but I want to make it work on Layouts.

Here is my `OnTouchListener`

```
public static OnTouchListener buttonTinter = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Drawable d = v.getBackground();
                    if (d != null) {
                        d.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 155, 155, 155),
                                PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    Drawable d = v.getBackground();
                    if (d != null) {
                        d.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    }
                    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 300) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

The `synchronized` and the time part is just to avoid a bug of touching 2 buttons at the same time. So, it works perfectly in Buttons or ImageButtons, but nothing happens when I set it to RelativeLayouts or LinearLayouts (**there is no bug, it just ignore the code**). Does anyone have any suggestion?

**SOLUTION:**

The background of the layouts **must be a drawable, not a color**

Answer (score 0):

Have you made your layouts 'clickable'?

```
myLinearLayoutName.setClickable(true);
myRelativeLayoutName.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: It's already clickable, I've set it as well, but nothing happens.